# How to use jqgrid when your resultset size is too large to compute?

Tags: ajax, jquery-plugins, jqgrid

I'm attempting to use jqgrid. Unfortunately, I can't compute a resultset size because I'm using  a **very** large database and computing the size of the resultsets I'm providing is very slow. I can get data reasonably quickly, but getting a count of the resultset for my queries just isn't possible.

Is there a way to get around this? Perhaps by not using a pager, but instead using some kind of scrollbar? Is there any kind of standard technique that's being used by people out there to get around this? I looked at the virtual scrollbar and autoloading data while scrolling examples, but they both seem to require a total.

I *really* want to use jqGrid. I actually already have an implementation in one of my code branches that uses it, but its computing resultset sizes using a much smaller database. Does anyone have any suggestions on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this question was provided to me by OlegK. You can see his answer here:

http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/help/can-you-use-jqgrid-if-you-cannot-provide-a-resultset-size/

Answer (score 1):

Give a look to the [True scrolling Rows](http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html) sample.

It's under New in version 3.6 => True scrolling Rows

Comment: That looks great, and I'd love to use it, but will it work if I can't give it a total?

Comment: It seems that the sample does not need it. Look even here for more details `http://jollyroger.kicks-ass.org/grid_test/`

Comment: Nah, if you look with firebug you'll see that the records field is set.

Answer (score 0):

You could implement paging, and just retrieve data for the current page. I have implemented something similar where I had to retrieve 30,00o rows and it works great!